# Set variable value into json params - PHP

Tags: php, json

I built a rest integration for my Salesforce instance.

When I send the fixed json (without variable values) it works. But I'm doing a proof of concept and I need to pass some variables to the json and when I did it nothing happens.

I think that what I am trying to do is not possible (the way I am trying to), but I have not found any material that will help me understand how to pass a variable into a json.

However, what I did was:

I created a message field in the body of the HTML.

```
        <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Campo obrigatório">
            <span class="label-input100">Sua mensagem</span>
            <textarea class="input100" name="message" placeholder="Deixe aqui sua mensagem"></textarea>
            <span class="focus-input100"></span>
        </div>
```

Then, I retrieve the value of this field, and encode it for json

```
$mensagem = $_GET['message'];
$mens_json = json_encode($mensagem);
```

Finally, I'm looking for this variable (["$mens_json"]) and placing it into a json parameter.

```
$params = ("{\"Fields\":[{\"Name\":\"requestDefinitionId\",\"Value\":\"a3Hf0000000lTNaEAM\"},{\"Name\":\"client\",\"Value\":\"0053j00000A7rWLAAZ\"}],\"Answers\":[{\"QuestionId\":\"a3Df0000000qI63EAE\",\"Values\":[\"Reclama\u00e7\u00e3o\"]},{\"QuestionId\":\"a3Df0000000qHvsEAE\",\"Values\":[\"$mens_json\"]},{\"QuestionId\":\"a3Df0000000qHwREAU\",\"Values\":[\"Web\"]}]}");
```

The body, that works on Postman is the same that I saved on my php code. Just to try to integrate. Now I will try to create the json with variables.

```
{
  "Fields": [
    {
      "Name": "requestDefinitionId",
      "Value": "a3Hf0000000lTNaEAM"
    },
    {
      "Name": "client",
      "Value": "0053j00000A7rWLAAZ"
    }
  ],
  "Answers": [
    {
      "QuestionId": "a3Df0000000qI63EAE",
      "Values": [ "Reclamação" ]
    },
    {
      "QuestionId": "a3Df0000000qHvsEAE",
      "Values": [ "Solicitação de Serviço aberta por qualquer integração web" ]
    },
    {
      "QuestionId": "a3Df0000000qHwREAU",
      "Values": ["Web"]
    }
      ]
}
```

***EDITED FROM HERE***
After changes, the json generated by json_encode is:

```
{ "Fields": [ { "Name": "requestDefinitionId", "Value": "a3Hf0000000lTNaEAM" }, { "Name": "client", "Value": "0053j00000A7rWLAAZ" } ], "Answers": [ { "QuestionId": "a3Df0000000qI63EAE", "Values": [ "Reclamação" ] }, { "QuestionId": "a3Df0000000qHvsEAE", "Values": [ "RODRIGO BARCAT" ] }, { "QuestionId": "a3Df0000000qHwREAU", "Values": [ "Web" ] } ] }array(2) { ["Fields"]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["Name"]=> string(19) "requestDefinitionId" ["Value"]=> string(18) "a3Hf0000000lTNaEAM" } [1]=> array(2) { ["Name"]=> string(6) "client" ["Value"]=> string(18) "0053j00000A7rWLAAZ" } } ["Answers"]=> array(3) { [0]=> array(2) { ["QuestionId"]=> string(18) "a3Df0000000qI63EAE" ["Values"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(12) "Reclamação" } } [1]=> array(2) { ["QuestionId"]=> string(18) "a3Df0000000qHvsEAE" ["Values"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(14) "RODRIGO BARCAT" } } [2]=> &array(2) { ["QuestionId"]=> string(18) "a3Df0000000qHwREAU" ["Values"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "Web" } } } }
```

and the json that I can use to integrate with salesforce is look like below:

```
("{\"Fields\":[{\"Name\":\"requestDefinitionId\",\"Value\":\"a3Hf0000000lTNaEAM\"},{\"Name\":\"client\",\"Value\":\"0053j00000A7rWLAAZ\"}],\"Answers\":[{\"QuestionId\":\"a3Df0000000qI63EAE\",\"Values\":[\"Reclama\u00e7\u00e3o\"]},{\"QuestionId\":\"a3Df0000000qHvsEAE\",\"Values\":[\"Solicita\u00e7\u00e3o de Servi\u00e7o aberta por qualquer integra\u00e7\u00e3o web\"]},{\"QuestionId\":\"a3Df0000000qHwREAU\",\"Values\":[\"Web\"]}]}");
```

I found nothing about why it happens or how can I generate the json as the second one that I paste above.

Thank you

Comment: Don't create your own json, you'll always run into issues. Instead, create an object or array, then use [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to make a properly encapsulated string.

Comment: I tried this a lot, but always get an error. I will update post with original json body. But I was unable to assemble an array in the correct format. What I did at the end was to take the body (which I put in my post now) and convert it to have this result that you saw in the variable $params.

Comment: If that's the original JSON body, then you need to decode it then insert it, or else it's going to get double encoded

Comment: I think I understand, but that's where the difficulty is. This body works as expected, but it has fixed data. I'm having trouble creating an array to have dynamic json, according to my form. Thank you, aynber

Comment: I have edited my post and add new info starting at: EDITED FROM HERE After changes, the json generated by json_encode is. Can you help me how I format the json as I type on edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on aynber's comments, you'll have to

- turn your JSON data into an array first (via `json_decode()`)
- then insert the value(s) you want to insert into the array
- then turning the array back into a JSON string (via `json_encode()`).

So, assuming you want to insert this value...

```php
$message = "Solicitação de Serviço aberta por qualquer integração web";
```

...into this JSON string (shortened for readybillity)...

```json
{
    "Fields": [
        ...
    ],
    "Answers": [
        {
            "QuestionId": "a3Df0000000qI63EAE",
            "Values": [
                "Reclamação"
            ]
        },
        {
            "QuestionId": "a3Df0000000qHvsEAE"
        },
        {
            "QuestionId": "a3Df0000000qHwREAU",
            "Values": [
                "Web"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

...you'll need to do:

```php
// Step 1: Turn your raw JSON data into an array
$data = json_decode($json, true);

// Step 2: Loop the data until you've found the piece of data you want to append to
foreach ($data['Answers'] as &$answer) {

    // For the question id, you'll want to define a variable up front
    if ($answer['QuestionId'] == 'a3Df0000000qHvsEAE') { 

        $answer['Values'] = [$message]; // Step 3: Insert what you want to insert
    }
}

// Step 3: Turn the array back into JSON
echo(json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

This gives you:

```json
{
    "Fields": [
        ...
    ],
    "Answers": [
        {
            "QuestionId": "a3Df0000000qI63EAE",
            "Values": [
                "Reclamação"
            ]
        },
        {
            "QuestionId": "a3Df0000000qHvsEAE",
            "Values": [
                "Solicitação de Serviço aberta por qualquer integração web"
            ]
        },
        {
            "QuestionId": "a3Df0000000qHwREAU",
            "Values": [
                "Web"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I've set both `json_encode()` flags (`JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`) only to improve readabillity, you can safely leave them out.

Comment: Hi, nosurs. Thank you and apologies for delay. I have done changes as you said and now the value was attached to json. Just more one question. The json generated gives me an error when I try to integrate. string(225) "[{"errorCode":"APEX_ERROR","message":"System.JSONException: Unexpected character ('-' (code 45)) in numeric value: expected digit (0-9) to follow minus sign, for valid numeric value at input location [1,3]\n\n(System Code)"}]"

Comment: I will update the main post to put the json generated and which one I can integrate. They are different.